# Can I pass an object into argparse.add_argument?

Tags: python, object, parameter-passing, argparse

Instead of having a bunch of literals scattered across calls to `add_argument`, like so:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo',
                    required=False,
                    metavar='bar',
                    type=str,
                    help='help message',
                    default='default')

parser.add_argument('--foo2',
                    required=False,
                    metavar='bar2',
                    type=str,
                    help='help message',
                    default='default')
```

I was hoping I could create a container first, and then add all the arguments in a loop.
Something like this:

```
for arg in argument_container:
    parser.add_argument(arg)
```

I'm not familiar enough with how python is accepting these parameters to understand if they can be abstracted out into some kind of object literal like I want.

Is there a way to abstract out all the parameters into a container first, and then add all the arguments at once through a loop as shown above?

Comment: Have you tried to do it?

Comment: I've tried passing in a dictionary, that does not work.  I've tried creating some kind of object literal as a named tuple, that did not work.  I looked at the implementation of add_argument, but I'm still not sure what can be accepted into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the `add_argument` parameters are keywords ones, which can be passed in via the `**kwargs` syntax.  For example:

```
In [90]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [91]: adict={"metavar":"bar", "help":"help message", "default":"default"}
In [92]: a1 = parser.add_argument('--foo', **adict)
In [93]: a1
Out[93]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default='default', type=None, choices=None, help='help message', metavar='bar')

In [94]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo bar]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo bar   help message
```

Here I created a small dictionary with some of the parameters, and passed those in via `**adict`.

I didn't include '--foo' in that dictionary because it is a positional parameter.  That could still be assigned to a variable, and passed in that way.

I saved a reference to the object returned by `add_argument`, and displayed that.  It shows how most of the parameters become attributes of the resulting `Action` object.

---

For your second argument:

```
In [95]: dest = "--foo2"
In [96]: adict={"metavar":"bar2", "help":"help message2", "default":"default2"}
In [97]: a2 = parser.add_argument(dest, **adict)
In [98]: 
In [98]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo bar] [--foo2 bar2]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --foo bar    help message
  --foo2 bar2  help message2
```

Obviously this could be generalized to work with lists of dictionaries, or with a function that takes some parameters, generates missing ones and calls `add_argument` in this way.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't `**`ing the dictionary when passing it in.

Answer (score 3):

To get both the `*args` and `**kwargs` in the same list, you can add them as parts of a tuple:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some strings.')

args = [(('--foo', '-f'), {'help':'Foo help', 'required':False, 'type':str, 'default':'foo'}),
        (('--bar', '-b'), {'help':'Bar help', 'required':False, 'type':str, 'default':'bar'})]

for arg in args:
    parser.add_argument(*arg[0], **arg[1])

parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
```

Thus, first part of the tuple is another tuple, containing the different name of the argument, then the second part of the (outer) tuple is a dict with the keyword arguments.